# Jquery Function Triggers

Tags: jquery

I'm struggling with something that I expect should be fairly straightforward! - is it possible to have more than one function trigger - for example in the below code img.swap triggers the event -

```
 $("ul.navigation img.swap").live("mouseover mouseout",
      function (event) {{);
```

Is it possible to add other triggers - for example if I had a different image class such as img.over could this be added in something similar to -

```
$("ul.navigation img.swap" & "img.over").live("mouseover mouseout",
      function (event) {});
```

Thanks
paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a comma.

`$("ul.navigation img.swap, img.over")`

Comment: Yep if OP want only inside the "navigation" list then it should be: `$("ul.navigation img.swap, ul.navigation img.over")` :)